# Querying Microsoft Graph API for user sourced from other Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have an Azure AD in which I have some users that are sourced from a another Azure AD. I have no problem authenticating these users from my MVC web application using OpenID Connect Owin middleware, but when trying to get user profile by querying https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me in the Microsoft Graph API, I get a NotFound result. The user name (email) in the error message is with an underscore instead of an @ sign.

Getting user profiles for users within the original AD works just fine.

Any ideas? Is this a known issue and is there a way to get around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this issue. This is a known bug in API affecting /me query in the context of users who are sourced from different Azure AD tenant. ETA for fix is around 2 weeks. Expect an update here when fix is available.

[Update-2016-2-16:Fix is now in place. Please give it a shot]

Comment: Fix is now in place. Please give it a shot.

Comment: What about getting email messages for users sourced from a different Azure AD with the "me/messages" call? This currently gives me an "UnknownError" response with an empty error message.